# Python appending itself

Tags: python, recursion

I have a little bit of a silly question and I am relatively new to programming. I am currently taking data structures and I was reading our textbook. We are currently on recursion. The book brings up the idea of A.append(A) and B.append(B) where A=[2] and B=[2].  The book then says that this will cause a recursion error but their description of why that was the case wasn't the best. Could anyone explain this to me? Thank you very much!

Comment: It won't cause an error, so I'm not sure what they're talking about there (it could be a *very* outdated text mentioning old behavior). If you try this, you'll see the list will display as `[2, [...]]`. Unless they're referring to code they wrote, in which case the answer will depend on that code.

Comment: It causes a *reference cycle*, which could prevent the list from being reclaimed using reference counting alone (but that's what the garbage collector is for). It could cause an unwary function to enter infinite recursion, for example `def f(x): return f(x[0]); f(A)`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for details on how to best help us help you. In addition, you can follow the guidance on creating a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Finally, you can refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems